# poulating a list with Integer IDs that exists in sql DataTable

Tags: sql-server, list, c#-4.0, datatable

i have an integer list :

```
    List<int> AllowedLinks = new List<int>();
```

i have a datatable that contains integerIds .. i m trying to get those into this list through iteration but its giving error: input string not in correct format ..

//GetDataTable is a function returning a datatable

my code:

```
        DataObj = new DAL();
        DataTable dt
    dt = DataObj.GetDataTable("GetAllowedLinksForUserRole",1);
    foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        AllowedLinks.Add(Convert.ToInt32((myRow).ToString()));
    }
```

i do not want my list to be of datarow type because i will be needing integers for later manipulation!

Comment: Try debugging the code and see what values your getting in myRow and moreover use the column name .Example myRow["Column1"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should index the column where your ID is located in the datarow
In my revision of your code I use the var x as a placeholder.
You need to set the index of the column in your datatable that contains the integer value.
Better, you could also use its name

```
DataObj = new DAL(); 
DataTable dt 
int x = 0; // <= here 0 is the index of the column with the IDs 
int name = "ID"; // <= here ID is the name of the column with the IDs
dt = DataObj.GetDataTable("GetAllowedLinksForUserRole",1); 
foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows) 
{ 
    AllowedLinks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(myRow[x])); 
    // This is to use column name
    // AllowedLinks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(myRow[name])); 
}
```

Note: the code above assumes that your integer column doesn't contains NULL values.
If this is not the case then a test is needed before converting the column value to an integer

```
    AllowedLinks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(myRow[x] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : myRow[x]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in quickwatch. There must be a property/index associated with the row myRow.
You can't directly access the datarow like `Convert.ToInt32((myRow).ToString())`

Instead you need to access it via

```
Convert.ToInt32((myRow.propertyname).ToString())
```

or `Convert.ToInt32((myRow[incrementedindex]).ToString())`